# Calling a procedure inside an other procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, procedure

I'm new to PL/SQL i need help in solving this - I have written 2 procedure how do I call the first procedure inside the second procedure. Here are the 2 procedures.
Porcedure 1:

```
 create or replace procedure propl1(
 activeplayer player.active_player%type,
 pname out player.player_name%type,
 spl out player.specialization%type, cur out sys_refcursor)
 is begin
 open cur for select player_name, specialization from player p, country c 
 where p.country_id=c.country_id and active_player=activeplayer order by country_name desc;
 end propl1;
 /
```

Procedure2:

```
  create or replace procedure player_runs(
  pname player.player_name%type, 
  runs out score_details.runs_scored%type,
  sixes out score_details.sixes%type)
  is begin
  select runs_scored, sixes into runs, sixes from player p, score_details s
  where p.player_id=s.player_id and player_name=pname;
  end player_runs;
  /
```

I want to call procedure 1 inside procedure 2.

Comment: **call procedure inside another procedure** in the sense, what you need exactly.

Comment: Exhausted -  i want propl1 to get executed when player_runs is run.

Comment: just call the procedure inside the player_runs like `player_runs(your parameters....)`

Comment: Yes, i did that. It worked. Thank you.
But is it the only way to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ... I can't even...

Answer (score 0):

You can give procedure name along with parameter from where you need to call another procedure.

e.g.

```
Begin
   proc_sample(input_param1, input_param2);
end;
```

/